# How do I increase ebs partitions volume size on aws ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, partitioning, volume

While I was deploying an application on some partition (on aws-ec2 instance) I got fatal error I'm **out of space on this block** `No space left on device`.

How do I increase ebs partitions volume size on aws ec2?

Comment: Which partition, root? E in EBS stands for Elastic. Just resize the volume in console to what you want. Obviously then you have to resize your partition from withing the OS to use the new space. If not sure how, spin up new instance, and test it out there. And before you attempt doing this on your primary one, make a snapshot of it for backup purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. Go to your amazon machine and run `lsblk` (ls block) - useful Linux command  which lists information about all or the specified block devices (disks and partitions). It queries the /sys virtual file system to obtain the information that it displays. The command displays details about all block devices excluding except RAM disks in a tree-like format by default.)

   ```
   NAME           MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
   loop0            7:0    0 93.9M  1 loop  /snap/core/123
   loop2            7:2    0   18M  1 loop  /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/456
   loop3            7:3    0   18M  1 loop  /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/789
   loop4            7:4    0 93.8M  1 loop  /snap/core/777
   xvda           202:0    0   20G  0 disk
   └─xvda1        202:1    0   20G  0 part  /
   xvdb           202:16   0   20G  0 disk  /home/boot
   xvdc           202:32   0   20G  0 disk
   ├─xvdc1        202:33   0   10G  0 part
   |  └─cryptswap1 253:0    0   10G  0 crypt
   └─xvdc2        202:34   0   10G  0 part
     └─crypttmp   253:1    0   10G  0 crypt /tmp
   xvdd           202:48   0   50G  0 disk
   └─enc_xvdd     253:2    0   50G  0 crypt /home
   xvde           202:64   0  8.9T  0 disk
   └─enc_xvde     253:3    0  8.9T  0 crypt /var/data
   ```
2. Locate your disk volume name of the specific partition.
3. Go to your amazon aws account -> ec2 -> instances ->  Description Panel -> Block Devices -> Click on the right block -> Click on the volume id -> Right CLick on the block id -> Modify Volume -> Select The correct size

[image]

4.ssh your machine and perform  the following commands (on the correct volume - in my example I chose increasing `/home` which is under `enc_xvdd`):

```
sudo cryptsetup resize enc_xvdd -v
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/enc_xvdd
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "growpart" and "lvextend" based on what partition type you have .

https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/LVM-HOWTO/#extendlv

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html